# Найти количество равнобедренных треугольников с целочисленными сторонами

Tags: python, алгоритм

Как найти количество равнобедренных треугольников с целочисленными сторонами при условии что каждая сторона должна быть не более заданного числа?

Задача за 9-10 класс. Лучше всего будет если вы решите ее используя код попроще

[image: Фото условия]

Comment: Лучше всего будет если вы решите ее самостоятельно.

Comment: Ну вообще, сегодня 6 декабря, а не 5.

Answer (score 3):

```
n = int(input())
print( n//2*(n//2) + n*(n - n//2) )
```

Comment: Я пересчитал, получилось как у тебя :)